# elasticsearch multiple key documents for aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Our elastic search document currently has  following fields: Id, cityId.

It's very easy to aggregate if each document's  city field has only 1 cityid i.e. cityid = 1.

But how can we aggregate on cityid if some document have multiple cityid values?

For example, if some document has cityid as (1,2), this shouldn't be treated as a new cityid i.e. (1,2) but this document should consider cityid 1 and cityid 2 as separate keys while aggregation on cityid for these documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the `cityid` field as an array this will work perfectly.  Example:

```
POST index1/type/
{
   "cityid": [1, 2] 
}
```

What **won't** work is if you store it like this:

```
POST index1/type/
{
   "cityid": "1,2" 
}
```